# Firebase OAuth won't work for external domain which has a CNAME record

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a domain **xyz.com** which used Firebase Authentication service, and xyz.com is whitelisted in the authorized domain list. So if I do any login (social providers / email), there is no problem.

I have another domain called **abc.com**, and I set up a CNAME for **sub.abc.com** to access **sub.xyz.com**. Now there is problem. When I access sub.abc.com, it would actually show the exact same page as sub.xyz.com. But when I tried to login via external providers say Twitter, Facebook, it won't allow to do so. Interesting is for email login, there is no problem.

But once I added abc.com as an authorized domain, then login works fine.

So just want to check is this expected? Firebase will not recognize any external domains which actually CNAME to the whitelist domains?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Your question currently has multiple questions, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I suggest trimming the text down to a single question in order to avoid it being closed.

Comment: Updated @DougStevenson